# Bind input model to typed fields

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a form with several input fields and radio buttons. Instead of binding these objects to String typed fields and then remap it to my model class, it would like to do this directly.

```dart
<input type="text" ng-model="myObject.intField" />
```

The controller would have a member like this:

```dart
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

class MyObject {
  int intField;
}
```

This will generate errors if the users enters any value, since  it's a string and not an int. In AngularJS this is no problem, since everything is dynamically typed.

This should also be possible with more complex types than an int.

Comment: Adding the Dart tag to all Dart related questions helps so that more people see your question and your chances getting an answer is much higher. I sometimes look up questions with Dart-related tags which don't have the dart tag and many of them are unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

```dart
<input type='number' ...
```

As far as I know this should do what you want.

In Angular.js you can do this because JavaScript converts between String and Num as needed but Dart doesn't.

Comment: This works for numbers, but I would also like to use this for more complex types.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your requirement? Your question only mentions `int`. As far as I know all (or at least most) `<input type='xxx'>` types are already supported. (I'm not sure about the state of file though).

Comment: For example if I want to map a date property or a field with a custom class.